# Use dinamically loaded class libraries with JAXB and JEE application server

Tags: dynamic, jar, jaxb, jax-rs, moxy

I was wondering if the following is possible:
1. I have a JAX-RS application deployed on a JEE server (lets say glassfish)
2. The JAX-RS application uses a jaxb context on incoming requests:

```
@POST
@Path("/mypath")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML + "; charset=UTF-8", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + "; charset=UTF-8"})
public ReportResponse accept(String request, @Context HttpHeaders headers){
StringReader reader = new StringReader(request);
IRequest req = (GenericRequest) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
```

Where:

IRequest is a generic request representation, and a GenericRequest is its base implementation.
Unmarshaller is bound to a specific package "org.myapp.entities".

3. I have different class libraries, that contain simple classes, that are all extending GenericRequest, and are all in the "org.myapp.entities" package.

So my question is:
If I deploy a new class library on the application server, as defined in step 3., will the JAX-RS endpoint know about it (step 2.).

So I create e.g.
NonGenericRequest extends GenericRequest and package it into mylibrary.jar, and deploy it in glassfish admin, will the following work:
1. The request (NonGenericrequest) sent to /mypath will be unmarshalled to an IRequest object?

(We use moxy as jaxb provider).

Thanks for your help!